# How to set up Ocelot with claims (roles)?

Tags: .net-core, claims, ocelot

I am trying to setup Ocelot in an Api Gateway and I am stuck on Authorization. I have managed to setup claims and I can authorize with them inside my controllers. I add a claim to a user like this:

```
await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, configuration["InitialAdmin:Role"]));
```

Then I setup Ocelot with the following config:

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/home/user",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/home/user",
      "RouteClaimsRequirement": {
          "Role": "user"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/home/admin",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/home/admin",
      "RouteClaimsRequirement": {
        "Role": "SuperAdmin"
      }
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5000"
  }
}
```

Here is my ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddIdentity<CondatoUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        //Signin config
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;

        //Password config
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;

        //User config
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    })
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserManagementDbContext>();
           services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddOcelot(Configuration);
}
```

I then log into this gateway Api (It's a MVC project with the default UI for login/register/etc.) and try to visit the following URL:

```
https://localhost:5000/api/home/admin
```

However, I always get a 403 status back. When I remove `RouteClaimsRequirement`, it works. So I guess I am missing something, but I have no idea how as the documentation for `RouteClaimsRequirement` is a little sparse.

Can anybody help me out here? Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I have the same problem.

Comment: Nope, but I managed to get Azure API Management Services up and running. We are hosting our app exclusively on Azure so the integration works pretty well.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I posted a reply (below) that I think answers this pretty well. Feel free to mark as correct ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well it turns out that this can't be done using the predefined `ClaimTypes` in `System.Security.Claims`. Which is due to the fact that (app)settings json parsing can't handle a colon (:) in a dictionary key. Referring to [this issue](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/679) on the Ocelot repo.

The solution is to use a custom claim type, e.g. "Role" instead of `System.Security.Claims.Role`, which yields "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"

Comment: I am getting error at line var serviceDescriptor = services.First(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(IClaimsAuthoriser));, can you please help me?